# How do I place an image behind another, and then slide it up?

Tags: html, z-index, fadein, slidetoggle, slideup

I currently have two images "IMAGE A" and "IMAGE B". As of right now my intention is to fade in IMAGE A and then fade in IMAGE B behind it (all while remaining centered on the page). However, instead IMAGE B seems to be pushing up IMAGE A as it appears. I'm using z-index, but I might be doing it incorrectly because it isn't quite working out.

After fading in IMAGE B, correctly I also want to slide it right above IMAGE A. Thanks for your help!

[image: IMAGE A]

[image: IMAGE B]

I attached a jsfiddle to better demonstrate what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/YQwZ6/

### HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pocket').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(3000).delay(2000);
    $('#pop').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(8000).delay(2000);

});
</script>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="pics" align="center">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="200">
                                <center>
                                    <div id="pocket" style="z-index:5000"><a><img src="http://www.cjboco.com/assets/page-extras/cj-flashy-slideshow/image_a.jpg"/></a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div id="pop" style="z-index:100"><a><img src="http://www.cjboco.com/assets/page-extras/cj-flashy-slideshow/image_b.jpg"/></a>

                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

### CSS:

```
body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-repeat: repeat;
color: #333366;
}
#pocket, #pop {
position:relative;
display: none;
float:center;
}
#pics {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$('#pocket').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(3000).delay(2000);
$('#pop').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(8000).delay(2000);
```

To this

```
$('#pocket').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(8000).delay(2000);
$('#pop').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(3000).delay(2000);
```

And this

```
#pocket, #pop {
position:relative;
```

To this

```
#pocket, #pop {
position:absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

Now, just position the images where you want them to appear. If they need to be centered, use them inside a DIV that is relatively positioned, so you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.

Working a bit into your HTML, I cleaned it to this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pocket').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(8000).delay(2000);
            $('#pop').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(3000).delay(2000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pics" align="center">
        <div id="pocket" style="z-index:5000"><a><img src="http://www.cjboco.com/assets/page-extras/cj-flashy-slideshow/image_a.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div id="pop" style="z-index:100"><a><img src="http://www.cjboco.com/assets/page-extras/cj-flashy-slideshow/image_b.jpg"/></a></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#pics {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#pocket, #pop {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    float:center;
}
```

Comment: Image B is most definitely hidden behind Image A! Thanks. However image B is smaller than image A and I'd like it to appear in the true center of the page (same with image A). When I change #pocket, #pop to absolute it completely throws it off. The reason I placed it in the pic DIV was so that it would always find the center of the page even if the page was made smaller or bigger. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Use them inside another DIV that's positioned relatively to the page. I'll put that into my answer.

Comment: @user1886754: See [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14494076/1516616) Hopefully you are looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

See this example now:

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/8UHWr/)

If yes, then some changes given below:

**CSS:**

```
#pocket, #pop {    
    display: none;
    float:center;
}

#pocket {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
}

#pop {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 180px;
}
```

**Remove `z-index` values from the HTML code given below:**

```
 <div id="pocket" style="z-index:5000">
 and
 <div id="pop" style="z-index:100">
```

**Use jQuery:**

```
$('#pocket').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).delay(500);
$('#pop').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(4000).delay(500).fadeOut(500).animate({
    'z-index' : 3
}, 500).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: thanks a lot but no I was simply just trying to fade it in behind the main image (hide it behind) and then have it slide up on top of the main image (think of it in terms of an image peeking above the other.

Comment: Edited my answer with an updated demo link and code accordingly.